# Image upload. Convert ImageFieldFIle to string or buffer

Tags: python, django, image, file, django-storage

I made my storage to upload files to BackBlaze, I am overriding save method, one of its parameters is content, when I pass images, content's data type is ImageFieldFile. What is the best approach to convert ImageFieldFile into string or buffer?
I tried create a instance of StringIO and write there content and after that getting value, but it didn't work

```
_content = content.file.file  #getting _io.BytesIO
buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
buffer.write(_content)
file_data = buffer.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 1):

To install django-b2storage:

```
$ pip install django_b2storage
```

Then in your settings file, add the following:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_b2storage.backblaze_b2.B2Storage'
B2_ACCOUNT_ID = 'your_account_id'
B2_APPLICATION_KEY = 'your_application_key'
B2_BUCKET_NAME = 'your_bucket_name'
B2_BUCKET_ID = 'your_bucket_id'
```

Reference: https://github.com/amlatyrngom/django-b2storage